# How to put p:commandLink with p:graphicImage in a dynamic columns datatable

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, primefaces, facelets, jsf-2.2

I've followed the example of `<p:datatable>` dynamic columns feature in [**primefaces showcase**](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableDynamicColumns.jsf), and it works great.

Now what i want is to put instead of simple `<h:outputText>` columns, i want to put columns with `<p:graphicImage>` nested in `<p:commanLink>` which serves to show a `<p:dialogue>`.

in other words how can i use this :

```
<f:facet name="header">
   #{column.header}
</f:facet>
   #{car[column.property]}
</p:columns>
```

to get it to generate something like this :

```
<p:column headerText="R"
          style=" text-align: center;"
          width="10"
          rendered="true">
    <p:commandLink id="MRepShowButton" update=":form1:display" onclick="EditorDialog.show();"  title="Editer le compte rendu"> 
       <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{exam}" target="#{dyna.selectedExamen}" />  
       <p:graphicImage id="img1" value="/images/study_Report_icons/Text/0.png" rendered="#{exam.examen.rapport.rapportWrittenState == null}"/>
       <p:graphicImage id="img2" value="/images/study_Report_icons/Text/#{exam.examen.rapport.rapportWrittenState}.png" rendered="#{exam.examen.rapport.rapportWrittenState != null}"/>
  </p:commandLink>
</p:column>
```

Just to let you know i can programatically make it like this :

```
column.setWidth(String.valueOf(columnmodel.get(i).getWidth() - widthOptimizer));
CommandLink rapstatelink = (CommandLink) application.createComponent(CommandLink.COMPONENT_TYPE);

rapstatelink.setId("MRepShowButton");
rapstatelink.setTitle("Editer le rapport du patient");
rapstatelink.setUpdate(":formero");
rapstatelink.setOnclick("EditorDialog.show();");


ValueExpression value = ef.createValueExpression(elc, "#{exam}", Cotation.class);
ValueExpression target = ef.createValueExpression(elc, "#{dyna.selectedExamen}", Cotation.class);
rapstatelink.addActionListener(new SetPropertyActionListenerImpl(target, value));
ValueExpression value1 = ef.createValueExpression(elc, "#{dyna.toHTML(dyna.selectedExamen.examen.rapport.rapportWrittenFile)}", String.class);
ValueExpression target1 = ef.createValueExpression(elc, "#{dyna.html}", String.class);
rapstatelink.addActionListener(new SetPropertyActionListenerImpl(target1, value1));

GraphicImage rapstateimage = (GraphicImage) application.createComponent(GraphicImage.COMPONENT_TYPE);
rapstateimage.setId("img1");
ValueExpression show1 = ef.createValueExpression(elc, "#{exam.examen.rapport.rapportWrittenState == null}", Boolean.class);
rapstateimage.setValueExpression("rendered", show1);
rapstateimage.setValue("/images/study_Report_icons/Text/0.png");
rapstatelink.getChildren().add(rapstateimage);

GraphicImage rapstateimage2 = (GraphicImage) application.createComponent(GraphicImage.COMPONENT_TYPE);
rapstateimage2.setId("img2");
ValueExpression patsategraphExp = ef.createValueExpression(elc, "/images/study_Report_icons/Text/#{exam.examen.rapport.rapportWrittenState}.png", Object.class);
rapstateimage2.setValueExpression("value", patsategraphExp);
ValueExpression show2 = ef.createValueExpression(elc, "#{exam.examen.rapport.rapportWrittenState != null}", Boolean.class);
rapstateimage2.setValueExpression("rendered", show2);
column.setStyleClass("imagero");

rapstatelink.getChildren().add(rapstateimage2);
column.getChildren().add(rapstatelink);
table.getChildren().add(column);
```

*this approach of creating the whole datatable in the backing bean and bind it to the facelet does work with a major problem which is i should click twice on the command link to fire the action.(no nested forms and everything is compliant to [BalusC Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/hcommandlink-hcommandbutton-is-not-being-invoked)).

***Additional info:***
Primefaces 4.0.
JSF 2.2.

Comment: You really need a `<p:commandLink/>` in this case? If not, let us know. I have an example here using `<p:commandButton>`, but first i need to know if `<p:commandLink/>` is a must.

Comment: okay, i can work with <p:commandButton> too, just enlighten me.

Comment: no one answers the real questions :s

Answer (score 0):

This is an alternative using `<p:commandButton/>`:

```
<p:commandButton id="MRepShowButton" update=":form1:display" onclick="EditorDialog.show();" icon="custom-icon" />
```

Declare this in your CSS stylesheet (adjust the image path according to your project):

```
.custom-icon {
    background-image: url("#{facesContext.externalContext.request.contextPath}/resources/img/chart_stock.png") !important;
}
```

Comment: but how do i use it with #{car[column.property] that is my real question ?

Comment: The only question i've found in your topic was this: `in other words how can i use this <code> to get this <code>`. The code above does exactly the same thing you need, but in a `<p:commandButton/>` (you've said earlier that doing it in a `<p:commandButton/>` was no problem).

Comment: look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20787244/how-can-i-get-the-children-of-a-pcolumn

Answer (score 0):

Use **name** property, not *value* in **p:graphicImage**.

p:graphicImage uses *name* property (and not *value*) to match the image in the *resources* folder. If *name* is not provided, the *img* html element will not be rendered.

*Example (based on the PrimeFaces columns showcase):*

```
 <p:graphicImage name="images/#{car.year}.jpg" />
```

You can also use the *library* property (same result in this case).

```
 <p:graphicImage library="images" name="#{car.year}.jpg" />
```

Images and directories must exist in the `WebContent/resource` folder in your project.

Take also into account my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20789832/how-can-i-get-the-nested-components-of-a-pcolumn-in-a-facelet-using-el) about how to include p:commandLink into a p:columns block.